# Why is Sidekiq running in development environment on server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, sidekiq

in my nginx website config file (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/my_website` I have set:

`passenger_env_var RAILS_ENV staging;`

I'm using Sidekiq for sending emails, starting it like this:

`bundle exec sidekiq -q mailers -d -L log/sidekiq.log`

but my Sidekiq is having environment set to `development`. Why?

Do I have to set the environment explicitly when starting sidekiq? I thought it is set by the nginx config.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be configured by creating a file under `initializers/sidekiq.rb`

```
If Rails.env.development?
  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0', namespace: "name_{Rails.env}" }
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0', namespace: "name_{Rails.env}" }
  end
elsif Rails.env.staging?
  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url: 'redis://redis-xx.xxxx.xxxx.xx.xxx.amazonaws.com:6379/12', namespace: "name_#{Rails.env}" }
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: 'redis://redis-xx.xxxx.xxxx.xx.xxx.amazonaws.com:6379/12', namespace: "name_#{Rails.env}" }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Sidekiq's default environment is [development](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb#L227). One way to set it is to run sidekiq like this

```
bundle exec sidekiq --environment production
```

Comment: Ok, so when I want to run it in production I have to set it like this: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sidekiq -q mailers -d -L log/sidekiq.log`?

Comment: Well, I'm checking the code in the link you have sent and the real question than is why the ENV["RAILS_ENV"] is not set from the nginx configuration?

Comment: Sidekiq has nothing to do with nginx or passenger -- they do not share config.