# Devise user creation through FactoryBot leaking to development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, factory-bot, sidekiq

I am trying to test my app which contains some Devise models (one of them being User)

And I have found a peculiar behavior as my app was by chance running in the background (in development environment) at the time I was working on the tests:

I created a user :`FactoryBot.create(:user)` in a test console (`rails c -e test`) and saw in my dev console that a Devise confirmation email had been triggered by Sidekiq with the id of the record created in the test console, but trying to pick data with same User ID from the Development database.

(=> I received an email at the address in the development database, while the FactoryBot record had been assigned a dummy email address)

I have then checked this thread [Devise - Skipping user confirmation in Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168996/devise-skipping-user-confirmation-in-development) that helps confirm Devise records manually (by populating `confirmed_at` field).

Yet I am a bit concerned of anything happening in test environment could be leaking to another environment.
Is there something I forgot to configure in Devise or my Test environment ?

Comment: No, this is not a normal behavior. Devise simply uses whatever database connection your app does.

Comment: thanks @max. I realised that Sidekiq is booted with `bundle exec sidekiq` when booting the app through a procfile. Should I precise a specific environment to Sidekiq ? I am wondering if Sidekiq is not the entrypoint to potential environment leaks, yet I have never seen any specific concern about booting Sidekiq in a specific environment .. I always kinda thought Sidekiq was env dependent by default ..

Comment: regarding databases, data is clearly segregated properly ! FactoryBot creations only append data to the test database.

Comment: Ah, sorry I was just being a bit slow. Sidekick is obviously sending the emails in a delayed job. You might want to read the wiki article on testing https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing

Comment: And this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103347/why-is-sidekiq-running-in-development-environment-on-server

Comment: Thank you. It seems indeed we can't use Sidekiq the normal way but use rspec-sidekiq gem instead (seems it bypasses redis and use an env dependent array instead). Will do that first and read the full Mike Perham thread if it doesn't fix my issue.